# How to embed a TableViewController inside a TabBarController and retain TabBar while segueing to VC

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a TabBarController with a relationship segue to ViewController with a ContainerView that contains an embedded TableViewController.  This works fine, however from a cell in the TableViewController's TableView, I want to be able to segue to a subsequent ViewController (while still retaining the TabBar at the bottom of the screen).  In other words when I segue from the TableViewController to subsequent VC, subsequent VC is presented over the entire window (instead of also being embedded in the ContainerView).  See below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the tab bar is disappearing is because it's included in the same navigation stack as the view controllers it contains. This can be avoided by giving each tab bar item its own navigation stack. To do this, put a navigation controller between your tab bar controller and each of its view controllers:

[image]